# Can someone please help with recommendation of efficient tool to develop PHP Mysql CRUD web application?

Tags: php, web

I am asking if someone can please recommend a tool to build CRUD PHP MySQL applications in more efficient and faster way ?

Basically, I am updating series of HTML and PHP files like add.php, edit.php, index.php with the same information over and over again.

Is there a tool to do this job once instead of updating series of separate files ?

Comment: You could look into a PHP template engine, of instance [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/)

Comment: Also take a look at [Grocery CRUD](https://www.grocerycrud.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **[PHP CRUD](https://www.phpcrudgenerator.com)** Generator [Disclaimer: I'm the author]

PHPCG generates a **Bootstrap 4 Admin Dashboard** with **CRUD Operations** in a few clicks

PHP CRUD Generator is an easy-to-use Web Application for creating a complete Bootstrap 4 Admin Dashboard for any project using a MySQL database.

The application is separated into two parts: the **CRUD Generator** and the **Admin Panel** for the final user.

The CRUD Generator scans your database: structure, tables, fields and relationships.

All you have to do is select your options to create all the pages of the admin dashboard: lists of records, creation forms, editing forms, deletion forms.

The system is extremely complete and can be customized easily, allowing you to deal with any situation.

Lists can be filtered, the admin panel includes an authentication and user rights management module.

The full demo is available online. PHP CRUD Generator is sold at a ridiculously low price in comparison to the amount of work it will save you!

Comment: Looks ***very*** impressive for a mere $28